# Magento 2: Error coming from Iteraror.php when trying to access Store=>Configuration

Tags: magento2, error, installation

When I attempt to access my store's configuration, I get this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/vs1paymentb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
```

There's more to the error after that but it's too long to paste here. Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how to fix it?

The only extension currently installed is this:

```
https://ecommerce.makarovsoft.com/magento-direct-add-to-cart-and-checkout-link-for-magento-2.html
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: remove genrated and then run di:compile

Comment: Check by comment on system.xml whole file.
If issue will no more than there is something not working in the system.xml

Answer (score 0):

if the error is in definition, refer this to update your **system.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor_main_node" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="advancedcatalog" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" translate="label">
            <label>Advanced Catalog</label>
            <tab>vendor_main_node</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
            ....
```